# sort List of string using comparator

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparator

I have  -

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestCompare {

    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("10", "1", "20", "11", "21", "12");
    Comparator<String> cmp = new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(o1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2));
        }
    };
    Collections.sort(list, cmp);
}
```

At `Collections.sort(list, cmp);` there is an error  - `Syntax error on token "(", delete this token`. What is wrong in this syntax ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't have code directly in a class, it should be in a method like `main`:

```
public class TestCompare {
    public static void main() {
      List<String> list = Arrays.asList("10", "1", "20", "11", "21", "12");
      Comparator<String> cmp = new Comparator<String>() {
      public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return Integer.valueOf(o1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2));
      }
      };
      Collections.sort(list, cmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I run by eclispe this class when the main is an inner function ?

Comment: @URL87 Just use the `run...` wizard

Comment: it will crash when the source array contains non-numeric value

Answer (score 9):

You need to wrap your code in a method, not directly in the class block.

Answer (score 0):

At class level, only declarations (and initializer) blocks are allowed. Your first two statements are declarations (they are interpreted as field declarations, even though that is probably not your intention). The third is not a declaration, so it fails.

Declarations can be: methods, fields, constructors, inner classes

Answer (score 0):

Post 1.8 you can use lambda expression too.

```
public class TestCompare {
    public static void main() {
      List<String> list = Arrays.asList("10", "1", "20", "11", "21", "12");
        Comparator<String> cmp = (o1, o2) -> {
            return Integer.valueOf(o1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2));
        };
        Collections.sort(list, cmp);
     }
}
```